# Capture Shares From Twitter Only?

Tags: android, twitter, android-intent

this Manifest's code will allow my activity to capture any text data that were shared by any app:

```
<intent-filter
    android:label="my_label">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

I want my activity to capture the shares that comes from Twitter official app ONLY. I want it to appear only in the share list of Twitter app.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking, there is no way for an `<intent-filter>` to say "no, I only want to work with XYZ app". The only things that you could use for that sort of thing would be:

- custom permissions, where Twitter would have to modify their apps with a `<uses-permission>` element for your custom permission
- custom permissions, set to `android:protectionLevel="signature"`, which would require Twitter to sign their apps with your signing key
- a custom category, or some other proprietary tweak to their `ACTION_SEND` `Intent`, which would have the side effect of breaking everyone else for your benefit

None of those seem likely.